# ionic FileTransfer gives no result/errors/feedback, and then does do the success function

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework, file-transfer

I have an Ionic framework, where I have the FileTranser module loaded so I can take a picture and upload that. The 'take a picture' part works perfectly.

When I click the image so that it'll upload, it fires the overlay "Busy uploading", then that fades out and it'll do the oncomplete function.

The problem is that the actual uploading part does nothing. No errors, no notices, nothing in my logs, no actual XHR resouce (or any resource). This is making it quite hard to debug. Could anyone give me a push in the right direction?

*Ps: I'm doing this on my android, connected to Chrome's debugconsole*

```
$scope.takePicture = function() {
    var options = {
        quality: 90,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URL,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA
    };

    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(
        function(imageData) {
            $scope.picData = imageData;
            $scope.ftLoad = true;
            //~ $localStorage.setItem('fotoUp', imageData);
            //~ $localStorage.fotoUp = imageData;
            $ionicLoading.show({template: 'Loading picture...', duration:500});
        },
        function(err){ 
            $ionicLoading.show({template: 'Error loading...', duration:500});
        }
    )
}
//--------------------------
// Upload the photo
$scope.uploadPicture = function() {
    $scope.upload = {};
    $ionicLoading.show({template: 'Bezig met uploaden...'});
    var fileURL = $scope.picData;
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "file";
    options.fileName = fileURL.substr(fileURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
    options.chunkedMode = true;


    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(fileURL, "https://www.example.com/recieve_photos.php", viewUploadedPictures, function(error) {
        $ionicLoading.show({template: 'connection error...'});
        $ionicLoading.hide();
    }, options);
}

var viewUploadedPictures = function($) {
    $ionicLoading.show({template: 'Get uploaded pictures...'});
    $http.get('https://www.example.com/recieve_photos.php')
        .then(function (response){
            $scope.upload.result = response.data
        }).catch(function(error){
            $scope.error = error;
        });
    $ionicLoading.hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found other documentation, which showed how to use the result/response to debug more:

```
    var win = function (r) {
        console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
        console.log("Response = " + r.response);
        console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
        $ionicLoading.hide();
    }

    var fail = function (error) {
        alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
        console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
        console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
        $ionicLoading.hide();
    }
    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(fileURL, encodeURI("https://www.example.com/recieve_photos.php"), win, fail, options);
```

After that, I knew I got an error code 3, which allowed me to continue the progress.